# Does my encryption scheme make sense?

Tags: encryption, hash, signature, keys

I'm looking at a way to encrypt a file so that our software will only allow users with the proper license to use it (see details below). I have some notions on that topic, but barely more than knowing it's very easy to get things wrong. I'm sure what we're doing must be rather common (up to the details), but I wasn't lucky with my search results so far. As such both links and hints are welcome. And my apologies if I don't use proper terminology.

#### Description of the workflow

So far we've come up with two option. Option A is the clear favorite in the team, but in case business requires it we also have option B.

Option A:

- We have a bunch of images that customers can buy to display on their computer
- A customers wants to buy M images from us, each to be displayed on N of their computers
- Our software generates a "key" linked to the computer it's running on and the customer sends us the N generated keys
- We encrypt these MxN images and send them all as a single zip file, along with anything else we may need
- The customer opens the zip file in our software; that will copy M ciphertexts to disk, the ones that are allowed for that computer
- When the customer opens an image, we decrypt the ciphertext to a temporary file and run an external process to display it*

Option B is similar, except that all ciphertexts are already packaged in our installer. The user only buys a key to decrypt them

*This is an unfortunate weak point to our system, but necessary for now (may change in the future). We're not looking for perfect encryption, mostly something that makes it difficult to bypass by average users

#### Restrictions

- Each license is only valid for a single computer
- Clients don't get to see the plaintext image without a license
- The system must be easy to use for our customers

  - In particular there shall be no user input at all once the ciphertext is installed
- Customers may not have internet access
- All customers have access to the same set of images

  - But we may also create custom images for a specific client at some point
- A motivated client will be able to compare the plaintext and the ciphertext
- The decryption part will be written in C++

#### Optional, nice to have

- Signature as proof that the images are coming from us
- Tracability in case a clever user manages to repackage the image for use in another machine
- Temporal validity of the license (ex.: 1 year)

  - Tamper-proof (so a user cannot just change the system clock)
- If the decryption can be done in Python too it will give us freedom in the future

#### Current idea

After writing all this and reading the links proposed by stackexchange, I'm inclined to use a combination of symmetric and asymmetric keys for option A:

- Software contains two public keys 1 and 2 in code (RSA for both?)
- Software retrieves some ID, for example Windows product ID or MAC address, ...
- Software encrypts `ID` with public key 1 and sends the resulting `ciphertext_1` to the server
- Server uses private key 1 to decrypt `ciphertext_1`
- Server signs image with private key 2
- Servers computes `hash(ID+filename)` as key to encrypt the image + signature into `ciphertext_2` (using AES? Twofish? A simple password-protected zip file?) and sends it to the client
- To display the image, the software recomputes `hash(ID+filename)` to decrypt `ciphertext_2` and checks the signature with public key 2

Does that sound sensible? Does it matter if the signature is done on the plaintext as opposed to the `ciphertext_2`? I'm mostly unsure about if, when and how it's best to hash the ID. And whether or not I should add a "salt" like the image name, some hard-coded string, and/or text to communicate / store on disk.

Comment: Can you explain the sense of this task? 1) When one user see the image, he can make a screenshot and distribute multiple copies. 2) *we decrypt the ciphertext to a temporary file* - user can easily copy this file and the distribute it. Why so much complexity, if it can be worked around very easily?

Comment: 1) I put "image" for sake of simplicity. In reality it's a binary to be used in a processing pipeline, so not something you can easily capture

2) Yes indeed, I know this is a weak point. We're trying to find a better solution but for now we're stuck with this. But really the user would have to know we use a temp file, know what's inside, copy before we remove it, know how to use it (couldn't reuse with our software). I think it is enough obfuscation to stop an average user from circumventing it, no?

Comment: To *I think it is enough obfuscation to stop an average user from circumventing it, no?* - only your users can answer this question. I think id depends on the price. If users think it is very cheap, it may be easier to them to pay. If users think it costs too much, they will look for workarounds. Users don't need to have strong skills. One user can implement a tool to automate the workaround and can distribute it, or even sell it much cheaper than your tools. To me it looks like it has little sense to implement what you describe. But you decide what you do.